# searching for free database of any company

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, business-intelligence

i received an university project where i'm asked to build and analayze database of a company. the company can be of any type and it must have several tables, for example: airline company that sales ticket (tables will be: sales, customers, flights, airports, ... etc).

i'm searching for free and open database of such company, where can i find one?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fairly easily build a small database (items, orders) out of the chipotle dataset:  https://github.com/TheUpshot/chipotle.

In general, companies don't offer up their data to the public (there tends to be proprietary info in them).  Luckily you are more interested in the datamodel than the actual data.  That said, the reality is you want something simpler than a real company's db.   Real enterprise databases are unwieldly complicated - think of all the tables they will have related to things like sales tax rules for different localities.

I would start with something like what I mention above and expand it a little.  Or just spend a few minutes thinking about the different things you would need to track for a business (like an airline), and just build the datamodel from that.   You will get a much better experience and learn how things need to fit together.

Answer (score 2):

You're using one of those databases right now! Stack Overflow regularly publishes a data dump of their database, and Brent Ozar helpfully compiles it into a SQL Server database for people to practice query tuning and such. [Here's a link to the most recent version I could find](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/07/new-stack-overflow-public-database-available-2017-06/), but you can also search for something like "Stack Overflow Database" and I'm sure you'll be able to find other versions.

Additionally, if you want to run some queries of your own against the database without downloading the whole shebang and running SQL Server on your own machine, you can access a web-based service for querying the database directly at https://data.stackexchange.com/

Also note - if the goal of your project is to design a database, this might not be the way to go, since it's already done for you. But even if it doesn't give you something to design, it might still be helpful to study how it's set up to give you ideas for your own work.